# Can't run Flutter project on iPhone emulator: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=5)

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter

VirtualBox 6.1

Create virtual machine - MacOS 10.15 Catalina.

Install on virtual machine:

- Android Studio 4 + Flutter plugin
- XCode
- Java 8

In Android Studio create new Flutter project. And success run it on Android device in virtual machine. Nice.

Now I want to start Flutter project on iPhone emulator.

In terminal:

```
open -a simulator
```

As result start iPhone emulator. Nice.

[image]

But when I try to run Flutter app in virtual machine on iPhone emulator I get error:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...

```
Xcode build done.                                           92.3s
Exception: Unable to launch com.example.flutterTestProect on 693536C3-86AB-4A79-9799-66567435367A:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
com.example.flutterTestProect: -1
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=5):
The request to open "com.example.flutterTestProect" failed.
Unexpected error type.
Underlying error (domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain, code=3):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 693536C3-86AB-4A79-9799-66567435367A com.example.flutterTestProect --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project also if not have you tried running a basic activity app from your emulator?

Comment: @ThomasMorris Not help. Same error. Maybe the  problem is that simulator not launch completely (see screenshot - black screen on simulator). Why simulator not start completely?

Comment: @ThomasMorris I try to start simple Swift project from XCode. But simulator also not start completely. And simple Swift project can't run on simulator. Show error message.